# Specifiy JRE Container with gradle eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, gradle, java

Even when the properties for `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` are set to a specific JRE Version, will the classpathentry for the `JRE_CONTAINER` only be genarated as `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" exported="true"/>`, and the default JRE-Version under "Installed JREs" in the eclipse settings doesn't always match the JRE-Version I want to use within my project.

How can I ask gradle, to set the JRE_CONTAINER to a specific version when gradle is run with `gradle eclipse`?

---

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

ext {
    target = "1.5"
}

def jreContainer = 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER'

if (target == '1.4' || target == '1.5') {
    jreContainer += '/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-' + target
} else if (target == '1.6' || target == '1.7') {
    jreContainer += '/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-' + target
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers.clear()
        containers.add(jreContainer)
    }
}
```

Comment: I had trouble with containers.clear() with eclipse-wtp. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110502 for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

in my case
it work well like below

```
containers.add('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk6')
```

but 'jdk6' is user specific name

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that `containers.clear()` did not seem to have any effect and the container was added instead of replaced. I followed the answer from John Vasileff and came up with the following solution to make sure that the Eclipse JRE is the same as the target Java version (11 in my case), and not the Java version that happens to be on my PATH environment variable:

```
subprojects {
    eclipse.classpath.file.whenMerged { cp ->
        def containerPrefix = "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"
        cp.entries.findAll { it.path.contains(containerPrefix) }.each {
            it.path = "${containerPrefix}/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-${compileJava.options.release.get()}/";
        }
    }

    compileJava {
        options.release = 11
    }
}
```

**Update**:
Eventually I found that I the EclipseJdt supports the following (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseJdt.html):

```
eclipse {
    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 11
        targetCompatibility = 11
        javaRuntimeName = "JavaSE-11"
    }
}
```