# Eclipse is throwing "Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build."

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am getting the below error while building a gradle project on eclipse. The problem surfaced after updating the MAC OS to Big Sur.

**Details of Exception Stack Trace:**

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:86)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultProjectConnection.getModel(DefaultProjectConnection.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.CompatProjectConnection.getModel(CompatProjectConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.IdeAttachedProjectConnection.configureOperation(IdeAttachedProjectConnection.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.IdeAttachedProjectConnection.model(IdeAttachedProjectConnection.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.CachingProjectConnection.model(CachingProjectConnection.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.CachingProjectConnection.getModel(CachingProjectConnection.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.EclipseModelUtils.runTasksAndQueryModels(EclipseModelUtils.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$null$4(DefaultModelProvider.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$GradleConnectionOperation.runInToolingApi(DefaultGradleBuild.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2317)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.withConnection(DefaultGradleBuild.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$fetchEclipseProjectAndRunSyncTasks$5(DefaultModelProvider.java:75)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseProjectAndRunSyncTasks(DefaultModelProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$SynchronizeOperation.runInToolingApi(DefaultGradleBuild.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2317)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$SynchronizeOperation.run(DefaultGradleBuild.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.synchronize(DefaultGradleBuild.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizationJob.runInToolingApi(SynchronizationJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizationJob.runInToolingApi(SynchronizationJob.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiJob$1.runInToolingApi(ToolingApiJob.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2317)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '14.0.2'.
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.configure(DefaultConnection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.configure(AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.createConnection(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:86)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.17.0.I20200902-1800
java.version=14.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Java Version Installed on Mac OS Big Sur:

```
 java -version                                
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Output of Gradle Version being used:

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC
Revision:     b762622a185d59ce0cfc9cbc6ab5dd22469e18a6

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_261 (Oracle Corporation 25.261-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

Can anyone please help me with this? It seems there is a bug in eclipse but I don't see any fix delivered by the eclipse team yet.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is running under Java 14, and Gradle doesn't work for that version.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '14.0.2'.

If you change your Eclipse runtime to launch under 1.8, or set up your Gradle configuration such that it uses that JRE rather than the one that Eclipse is using, the error should go away.

Comment: I am unable to choose Java 8 in eclipse installer for the latest eclipse version as the MAC OS has been updated to latest (Big Sur).

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110502/choosing-the-correct-jre-version-in-gradle-with-eclipse

Comment: @SujataYadav In the Eclipse preferences in _Gradle_ a Java installation can be specified (the Java that is used to run Eclipse is only used by default). And by the way, Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) is outdated. Use Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) for the best Big Sur support.

Comment: Great. To help others, you can mark this answer as accepted? That way they’ll know what to do if they run into the future. You can do that by clicking the tick between the up and down arrows.